# print line that matches first field (bash)

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk, sed

I'm trying to read userinput, have that match the first field of a csv file, and print out the entire line.  Here's what i've come up with:

```
#/bin/bash
echo "enter number: "
read USERINPUT
LINENUMBER=$(awk -v FS=',' '{print $1}' < test.csv | grep -n "$USERINPUT") 
FULLLINE=$(sed -n $LINENUMBER\p test.csv)
echo $FULLLINE
```

The problem i'm running into is say i set USERINPUT=4  but my csv file has several lines like 4, 421, 444, etc.. i match all of them.  How do i make

```
grep -n "$USERINPUT"
```

only match exactly what it is set to and nothing else?

Comment: get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES: some day you'll write `PATH=foo` and then wonder why your script is broken.

Comment: Grep supports `\<` for 'left word boundary' and `\>` for 'right word boundary'. Search for `\<4\>` to only find '4' by itself without it capturing `421`, `444`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of printing the first column of every line, then using `grep`, you should just do the whole thing in awk:

```
line_number=$(awk -F, -v s="$number" '$1==s{print NR}' test.csv)
```

If you just want to print the line, that's simple:

```
awk -F, -v s="$number" '$1==s' test.csv
```

By the way, instead of using an `echo` followed by a `read`, you can use `read -p` which allows you to specify a prompt:

```
read -p "enter number: " number
```

Comment: thank you! i knew i could do it all in awk but my awkfoo is weak sauce. much appreciated.

Comment: What if line in test is like `my 4 input, more info`.  And user input is `4`.  This will not hit, since split by `,` will give `$1` = `my 4 input`.

Comment: @Jotne From the question it appeared that the field would be just "4".

Answer (score 2):

```
#/bin/bash
read -p "enter number: " num
grep "^$num," test.csv
```

Comment: You should probably make that `egrep "^$num(,|$)"` so it'll work even when theres just 1 field in the file and you could even use `egrep "^($num)(,|$)"` if you wanted the user to be able to specify multiple lines at the same time as `3|7|12` or `3*` or...

Answer (score 0):

The -o grep option prints only what matches the regular expression.

E.g.

```
grep -o '.*USERINPUT.*'
```

or

```
grep -o '^USERINPUT.*'
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
#/bin/bash
echo "enter number: "
read USERINPUT
# for a var assignation and print content
 FULLLINE=$(egrep "^${USERINPUT%% *}," test.csv )
 echo $FULLLINE
# for only a print
 egrep "^${USERINPUT%% *}," test.csv
```

- Use of egrep to include deleimiter (start line and coma around the input)
- Use of a small input test removing trailing space via `${VarName%% *}`